# Showing a Fourier Series for $\sin (x)$ on $(0,\pi)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm not sure how to type math symbols on here so I'll try to be as clear as possible. My homework problem wants me to show that the *Fourier cosine series* for $\sin\left(x\right)$ on $\left(0,\pi\right)$ is
$$
\frac{2}{\pi} -
\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
\frac{\cos\left(2nx\right)}{4n^{2} - 1}
$$
I spent an hour on this problem the other day and filled up an entire board at my school and I got close to the answer, but I was still off by quite a bit. I think my problem is that I don't know how to find my $a_{0}$ term. My book is horrible and doesn't explain anything. I'm using the Springer *Applied PDE* book by *J. David Logan* if that is any indication to you, lol. I know I have to do several integration by parts as well. If someone can just start me on the right track I can roll with it. Thanks.

Comment: I just add some $\LaTeX$. You can check them. There is a nice tutorial overhere http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 3):

The Fourier Cosine series for $\sin(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$ is given by

$$\sin(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx)$$

where $a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\cos(nx)\,dx$.

Note that $a_0=\frac{4}{\pi}$ and $a_1=0$.  For $n\ge  2$, we have

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\cos(nx)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi (\sin((n+1)x)-\sin((n-1)x))\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{\pi}\left. \left(\frac{\cos((n+1)x)}{n+1}-\frac{\cos((n-1)x)}{n-1}\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}-1}{n+1}-\frac{(-1)^{n-1}-1}{n-1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\left((-1)^{n+1}-1\right)\frac{2}{n^2-1}\\\\
\end{align}$$

For $n$ odd, $a_n=0$.  For $n=2m$ we have

$$a_n=-\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{1}{4m^2-1}$$